# Mime type via htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

I want to know what exactly does the above htaccess code do. Dose it tell the server that html files are php files or inform the browser that .html files are php files.

Who are they talking to browser or server or both . I know that the below code informs the browser to force download files but do they also inform the server

```
AddType  application/octet-stream  .doc .xls .pdf
```

Also are htaccess specific to apache or other servers support them too

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this would help? http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=7584

or this: http://www.seas.upenn.edu/cets/answers/addtype.html

EDIT: And .htaccess files are supported by most server types. Well, any server if they are configured to look for them.

Comment: Neither lighttpd nor nginx does support .htaccess files.